# TypeScript - can a generic constraint provide "allowed" types?

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-constraints

Given the following code...

```
type Indexable<TKey, TValue> = { [index: TKey]: TValue }
```

This produces the following error:

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

Is there a way to constrain `TKey` to be 'string' or 'number'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@TitianCernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) indicates, you can't use `TKey` as the type in an index signature, even if it is [equivalent to `string` or `number`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7374).

If you know that `TKey` is exactly `string` or `number`, you can just use it directly and not specify `TKey` in your type:

```
type StringIndexable<TValue> = { [index: string]: TValue }
type NumberIndexable<TValue> = { [index: number]: TValue }
```

---

**Aside**: TypeScript treats `number` is usually treated as a kind of *subtype* of `string` for key types.  That's because in JavaScript, indices are converted to `string` anyway when you use them, leading to this kind of behavior:

```
const a = { 0: "hello" };
console.log(a[0]); // outputs "hello"
console.log(a['0']) // *still* outputs "hello"
```

EDIT: Note that TS2.9 added [support for `number` and even `symbol` keys in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).  We will use `keyof any` to mean "whatever your version of TypeScript thinks are valid key types".  Back to the rest of the answer:

---

If you want to allow `TKey` to be *more specific* than `keyof any`, meaning only *certain* keys are allowed, you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type Indexable<TKey extends keyof any, TValue> = { [K in TKey]: TValue }
```

You'd use it by passing in a string literal or union of string literals for `TKey`:

```
type NumNames = 'zero' | 'one' | 'two';
const nums: Indexable<NumNames, number> = { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2 };

type NumNumerals = '0' | '1' | '2';
const numerals: Indexable<NumNumerals, number> = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2};
```

And if you don't want to limit the key to particular literals or unions of literals, you can still use `string` as `TKey`:

```
const anyNums: Indexable<string, number> = { uno: 1, zwei: 2, trois: 3 };
```

---

In fact, this definition for `Indexable<TKey, TValue>` is so useful, it already exists in the [TypeScript standard library as `Record<K,T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1466-L1471):

```
type NumNames = 'zero' | 'one' | 'two';
const nums: Record<NumNames, number> = { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2 };
```

I therefore recommend you use `Record<K,T>` for these purposes, since it is standard and other TypeScript developers who read your code are more likely to be familiar with it.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: The top solution: `StringIndexable` and `NumberIndexable` is exactly what I ended up doing! Very comprehensive, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can constrain TKey to be derived from string or number (using extends) but that will not satisfy the compiler. `index` must be either number or string, not a generic type or any other type for that matter. This is documented in  the [language spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4)