# How to constraint type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am defining the interface for a hash:

```
export interface Hash<ValType> {
    [key: string | number]: ValType;
}
```

This errors:

```
An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'. (parameter) key: string | number
```

Then I tried:

```
export interface Hash<KeyType extends number | string, ValType> {
    [key: KeyType]: ValType;
}
```

Same error.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: check both answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885489/can-a-typescript-generic-constraint-provide-allowed-types

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to use a generic for the key on an indexer. Instead, you need to create an interface for each key type:

```
export interface StringHash<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

export interface NumberHash<T> {
    [key: number]: T;
}

const x: StringHash<Example> = {};
const y: NumberHash<Example> = {};
```

Hopefully you can see that if the generic key worked, it wouldn't save you any effort *non-working example to demonstrate*:

```
export interface Hash<TKey, T> {
    [key: TKey]: T;
}

const x: Hash<string, Example> = {};
const y: Hash<number, Example> = {};
```

If this were possible, all you'd be achieving is moving where the word `string` and `number` appears in the expression each time you reference the `Hash`. (i.e. it moves from `NumberHash` to `Hash<number,`).

This was discussed in [issue #6641](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6641).