# Combining generics with index type

Tags: typescript

Since this works:

```
const f = <T extends string>(x: T) => x;
f("");

interface Dictionary<T> { [key: string]: T; }
const dict: Dictionary<number> = { a: 1 };
```

I was expecting following code to work as well:

```
interface MyRecord<Key extends string, Value> { [_: Key]: Value };
```

but compiler reports on `_`:

```
An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
```

Changing `Key extends string` to `Key extends string | number` does nothing (same error).

**What is the reason why it fails and how would look a correct solution?** (Preferably without using `Any` and similar.)

Edit1:

```
type XY = 'x' | 'y';
const myXY: XY = 'x';
const myString: string = myXY;
```

Since this works, I was assuming same holds with indexed types (subset of `string` can pose in a role of `string` which is required by indexed type).

Comment: Possible duplicate (well, the answer anyway) of [What is the Record type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript - can a generic constraint provide “allowed” types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885489/typescript-can-a-generic-constraint-provide-allowed-types)

Comment: Neither seems to be a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript is asking what `Record` is, and uses very similar, if not same, code which seems to be working for them while not for me. Answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885489/typescript-can-a-generic-constraint-provide-allowed-types actually says to use mapped types which seems exactly as what my (not working) code does.

Comment: You're not using mapped types `{[P in K]: V}`,  you're trying to use an index signature `{[p: K]: V}`.  They look similar but are different things (and the latter is an error... `K` can only be `string` or `number` in an index signature)

Comment: Oh, you are right. Still don't understand why it doesn't work with indexed types though. Why does it say `Key extends string` isn't a subset of `string`? Isn't `'a'|'b'` (or any string union) a subset of `string`?

Comment: where do you see "subset" mentioned?  It must be *exactly* `string` or `number`, not a subset of either.

Comment: If `Key` extends `string`, then `Key` is a subset of `string`? Or am I wrong? Then since indexed type accepts `string`, they should also accept any subset (since they are still a `string`). I am really confused...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - can a generic constraint provide "allowed" types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885489/typescript-can-a-generic-constraint-provide-allowed-types)

Answer (score 15):

Let's talk about [index signature types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). They have similar syntax and do similar-ish things, but they're not the same.  Here are the similarities:

- They are both object types representing a range of properties
- Syntax: both index signatures and mapped types use bracketed keylike notation within an object type, as in `{[Some Key-like Expression]: T}`

Now for the differences:

#### INDEX SIGNATURES

Index signatures describe *part of an object type or interface* representing an *arbitrary number* of properties *of the same type*, with keys from a certain key type.  Currently, these key type can only be *exactly* `string`, `number`, or `symbol`, or a "pattern template literal" types as implemented in [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) like `` `foo_${string}` ``, or a union of these.

- Syntax: The syntax for an index signature looks like this:

  ```
    type StringIndex<T> = {[dummyKeyName: string]: T}
    type NumberIndex<T> = {[dummyKeyName: number]: T}
  ```

  There is a dummy key name (`dummyKeyName` above) which can be whatever you want and does not have any meaning outside the brackets, followed by a type annotation (`:`) of either `string` or `number`.
- Part of an object type: an index signature can appear alongside other properties in an object type or interface:

  ```
    interface Foo {
      a: "a",
      [k: string]: string
    }
  ```
- Arbitrary number of properties:  an object of an indexable type is not required to have a property for every possible key (which is not even really possible to do for `string` or `number` aside from [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects).  Instead, you can assign an object containing an arbitrary number of such properties to an indexable type.  Note that when you read a property from an indexable type, the compiler will assume the property is present (as opposed to `undefined`), even with `--strictNullChecks` enabled, [even though this is not strictly type safe](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778).  Example:

  ```
    type StringDict = { [k: string]: string };
    const a: StringDict = {}; // no properties, okay
    const b: StringDict = { foo: "x", bar: "y", baz: "z" }; // three properties, okay
    const c: StringDict = { bad: 1, okay: "1" }; // error, number not assignable to boolean

    const val = a.randomPropName; // string
    console.log(val.toUpperCase()); // no compiler warning, yet
    // "TypeError: val is undefined" at runtime
  ```
- Properties of the same type: all of the properties in an index signature must be of the same type; the type cannot be a function of the specific key.  So "an object whose property values are the same as their keys" cannot be represented with an index signature as anything more specific than `{[k: string]: string}`. If you want a type that accepts `{a: "a"}` but rejects `{b: "c"}`, you can't do that with an index signature.
- Only `string`, `number`, `symbol`, or a pattern template literal is allowed as the key type: you can use a `string` index signature to represent a dictionary-like type, or a `number` index signature to represent an array-like type.  TypeScript 4.4 [introduced support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) for `symbol` and pattern template literals, and unions of these.

You can't narrow the index signature to a particular set of `string` or `number` literals like `"a"|"b"` or `1|2`.  (Your reasoning about why it should accept a narrower set is plausible but that's not how it works.  The rule is that no member of an index signature parameter type can be a "singleton" or "unit" literal type.

#### MAPPED TYPES

A mapped type on the other hand describes *an entire object type, not an interface,*  representing a *particular set* of properties *of possibly varying types*, with keys from a certain key type.  *You can use any key type for this*, although a union of literals is most common (if you use `string` or `number`, then that part of the mapped type turns into... guess what? an index signature!)  In what follows I will use only a union of literals as the key set.

- Syntax: The syntax for a mapped type looks like this:

  ```
    type Mapped<K extends keyof any> = {[P in K]: SomeTypeFunction<P>};
    type SomeTypeFunction<P extends keyof any> = [P]; // whatever
  ```

  A new type variable `P` is introduced, which iterates over each member of the union of keys `in` the key set `K`.  The new type variable is still in scope in the property value `SomeTypeFunction<P>`, even though it's outside the brackets.
- An entire object type: a mapped type is the entire object type.  It cannot appear alongside other properties and cannot appear in an interface.  It's like a union or intersection type in that way:

  ```
    interface Nope {
        [K in "x"]: K;  // errors, can't appear in interface
    }
    type AlsoNope = {
        a: string,
        [K in "x"]: K; // errors, can't appear alongside other properties
    }
  ```
- A particular set of properties: unlike index signatures, a mapped type must have exactly one property per key in the key set.  (An exception to this is if the property happens to be optional, either because it's mapped from a type with optional properties, or because you modify the property to be optional with the `?` modifier):

  ```
    type StringMap = { [K in "foo" | "bar" | "baz"]: string };
    const d: StringMap = { foo: "x", bar: "y", baz: "z" }; // okay
    const e: StringMap = { foo: "x" }; // error, missing props
    const f: StringMap = { foo: "x", bar: "y", baz: "z", qux: "w" }; // error, excess props
  ```
- Property types may vary: because the iterating key type parameter is in scope in the property type, you can vary the property type as a function of the key, like this:

  ```
    type SameName = { [K in "foo" | "bar" | "baz"]: K };
    /* type SameName = {
        foo: "foo";
        bar: "bar";
        baz: "baz";
    } */
  ```
- Any key set  may be used: you are not restricted to `string`, `number`, `symbol` or pattern template literals.  You can use any set of `string` literals or `number` literals.  You can also use `string` or `number` in there, but you immediately get an index signature when that happens:

  ```
    type AlsoSameName = { [K in "a" | 1]: K };    
    /* type AlsoSameName = {
        a: "a";
        1: 1;   
    } */
    const x: AlsoSameName = { "1": 1, a: "a" }

    type BackToIndex = { [K in string]: K }
    /* type BackToIndex = {
        [x: string]: string;
    }*/
    const y: BackToIndex = { a: "b" }; // see, widened to string -> string
  ```

  And since any key set may be used, it can be generic:

  ```
    type MyRecord<Key extends string, Value> = { [P in Key]: Value };
  ```

---

So that's how you would make `MyRecord`.  It can't be an indexable type; only a mapped type.  And note that [the built-in `Record<K, T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) is essentially the same (it allows `K extends string | number | symbol`), so you might want to use that instead of your own.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-gANKw3AWbDBrROSxeZAgUhLWhcwPIKDZwwwTkQD2QByhzKISr4LmkZoJT2wZutiDt5Cd7s1vAFrBFxglssV9Q0LlcQ02y6xiC0xTJwd1NDpsB-Gi5lBQHwrJynAA+F628Fv9+sJyiRVK4qygNgRSPfyvaz7NsuxAUcF4nGcIqvJMVLTFkEDfJwf5VgBF7rJBHRwk4CJQDIQaYmgUD3GArCflAliIYeGb-qsaFATsF57CMhzHBsACOUi4L41pQuuWE4Xg9gYkRvKkaYwjmFYdjQBIDwaMEHinrWdGGNmLQwvxwxQLY5IAORopm2zKZJ8A2PYsQDuIACCeISrJ4hLApNSig6TlKeePjrKpfG+thWk6cg+leIZVoMpUqCYjgoxXCixGPIMYlxKI+4ChA-KCieZ51peLhPj4D55YcPiqR+witAAVFAKYwKl6XQI5wieORtE5deZSNZ4D6+AV7VNSxz4nO1-BQOVrR7tZtlODVgp1Zlyl+E+QIlf2ZWVSmNkStNaWpdkTneBe-i9Z4QLAkNI1jbBNJcVAG1TbVO1VhCPjAiM+0LQI43QAAQnYdCEE4yh4HN57RAU9YfatVWDj9th-QDYa4LtHWKddoPcIUKRDaNZHaDDcOA4jVZvXIvEwqwtwjNaiA4MgUZVa4aNQAAtKQaOUuz4kcxzQA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the typescript's [`Record<Key, Value>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) utility instead of the index signature.

```
interface MyObject<K extends string = string> {
  someProperty: Record<K, any>;
}
```