# typescript index signatures vs Record<Keys, Type> return type for objects with uknown properties

Tags: typescript

I have a `getQueryParams` function that accepts a string and returns a plain object with unknown properties:

```js
function getQueryParams(s) {
  if (!s || typeof s !== 'string' || s.length < 2) {
    return {}
  }

  return s
    .substr(1) // remove `?`
    .split('&') // split by `&`
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const a = curr.split('=') // split by `=`
      return { ...acc, ...{ [a[0]]: decodeURIComponent(a[1]) } }
    }, {})
}

// getQueryParams('?mode=action&oobCode=code')
// returns {mode: "action", oobCode: "code"}

// getQueryParams('')
// returns {}
```

Typescript, offers [Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and [`Record<Keys,Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
// index signature
type NameMap = {
  [key: string]: string
}

export function getQueryParams(s: string): NameMap { ... }
```

```
// Record<Keys,Type>
type NameMap2 = Record<string, string>

export function getQueryParams(s: string): NameMap2 { ... }
```

So my question is, which one do I use? Is it just a matter of preference? Can I use both interchangeably? Or is there an appropriate time to use Index Signatures or `Record<Keys,Type>`?

Comment: The types `Record<string, string>` and `{[key: string]: string}` are equivalent.  But in general `Record<K, V>` cannot be represented by an index signature type for arbitrary `K`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331699/2887218) for more info.  There's also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript).  If you still have questions, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Index signature enables you to name the key, as in `{ [username: string]: UserData }`, whereas using Record it would be `Record<string, UserData>`. Apart from that, the two can for most purposes be used interchangeably. The Record<Key, Type> style is more handy for situations where you don't need to name the key variable.

Comment: is `{ username: string: UserData }`  syntactically correct? I understand what you are saying, but not sure if this is correct

Comment: It should be `{ [username: string]: UserData }`, and such key naming is really only useful for documentation, since it is unobservable in the type system (e.g., the types `{[foo: string]: 0}` and `{[bar: string]: 0}` are equivalent)